# Preprocess list of tuples by keeping track of each word's counts in a tuple

Tags: python, list, nlp, tuples

I have the following list of tuples:

```py
words = [('This', 0), ('showed', 0), ('good', 0), ('Patency', 140), 
         ('of', 1), ('the', 1), ('vein', 7), ('graft', 30), ('with', 0), 
         ('absence', 2), ('.', 0), ('FINDINGS', 0), (':', 0), (2, 5)]
```

The variable `words` has the structure `[(token, n_of_occurrence)]`.

I want to preprocess `words` where I want to remove all tuples that their token is a digit, NAN, stopword, punctuation, and remove all duplicates in such a way I keep track of their occurrences. I am expecting to have as output:

```py
[('showed', 0), ('good', 0), ('patency', 140), 
 ('vein', 7), ('graft', 30), ('absence', 2)('findings', 0)]
```

---

I tried the following but end up with an appropriate output; an empty list.

```py
tokens = [w[0].lower() for w in [str(w) for w in set(words)] if (w[0] != 'nan' and 
                                                                 w[0].isdigit() != True and not 
                                                                 w[0].replace('.', '', 1).isdigit())]

items = [t for t in tokens if (t not in stopwords.words('english') and
                               t not in string.punctuation)]
```

here `items` will be my final preprocessed list of tuples.

Comment: What is the traceback you "end up with"?

Comment: Thanks! @Scott Hunter, for what I tried here, I got an appropriate output. I got a traceback when tried different approaches but end up with no solution so far.

Comment: ```str(w)``` turns your tuple into a string that looks like a tuple but is actually a string. In Python indentation is unbelievably important, you should try a linter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I tried with what was proposed as solutions and found the correct answer.

```py
tokens = [(w.lower(), cnt) for w, cnt in [(str(w), cnt) for w, cnt in set(words)] 
          if (w != 'nan' and 
              w.isdigit() != True and not 
              w.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit())]

items = [(t, cnt) for t, cnt in tokens if (t not in stopwords.words('english') and
                                      t not in string.punctuation)]
```

This code will output exactly what was expected in the question.

Comment: You could simplify your IF statements by extracting the "NOT" and making them into ORs. I.e.: if NOT (w=='nan' or w.isdigit() or w.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit())

Comment: How does your own answer spot duplicates?

Comment: Thanks! Vexen. I used `set(words)` to spot duplicates.

Comment: Oh cool. Python is such a lovely language :-) How do you sum the cnt values for the duplicates?

Comment: I actually don't sum, because the initial variable has already word occurrences.

Comment: If ("sublime",3) and ("Sublime",8) are listed separately, don't you want it to say ("sublime",11) in the answer? Or, will the original list really already list ("sublime",11),("Sublime",11)?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'd stick preprocessWords in a def(), and work on each case one by one. I.e., write the code to test for NaN, punctuation, each in a different block of code, rather than trying to do it all at once, and then fault-find each area seperately. Therefore:

```
def preprocessWords(words):
    goodwords = []           #This is Returned as the answer
    temp = []                #Used to spot duplicates
    for word,q in words:     #word gets tested against multiple criteria, if none match, the final "else" adds it to goodwords
        if isnumeric(word):
            pass     #Disregard purely numerical items. This also negatives strings such as "12.5".
        elif word in ";:,.!":        #Fill out full list of denied punctuation
            pass
        elif word in stopwords.words('english'):      #Denied, for some reason...
            pass
        elif word.lower() in temp:           #Duplicate. Temp only has .lower() values, so covert to lower
            pass
        else:
            goodwords.append([word,q])       #Gets returned as the answer
            temp.append(word.lower())        #List used to spot duplicates
    return goodwords
```

**Structure:** You COULD merge all of those into one mega line of "IF NOT (TEST1) OR (TEST2) OR (TEST3)" but whilst in development, I'd keep each test separate and it gives you a chance of adding print(word,"failed due to having punctuation") and print(word,"failed due to duplicate") whilst debugging.

**Duplicates:** If there are duplicates, surely you want to add up the q values? You didn't say in your question - but if so, on the "if word in temp" line, you'll want to add logic to += the q value in goodwords for that word.

**Punctuation-words**: You'll want to define a full list of punctuation. An alternative way would be to search for any word that is just one letter long, and then check to see if that letter is a-z, A-Z. But that would be more complicated than you think, given that á,é,í and lots of other possible letters from different language would also have to specified.